# Creating Simple PyGTK ComboBox Causes Error

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am attempting to create a simple PyGTK ComboBox. But when I run my code I get a runtime error:

```
'comboBox = gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(client_store)'
AttributeError: type object 'gtk.ComboBox' has no attribute 'new_with_model'
```

**How can I create a PyGTK combobox?** Its a very tricky process to create one of these widgets I am finding. Note I am using **PyGTK Version 2.24 on Python 2.7**

Any advice on how I can create a simple ComboBox would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
gtk.rc_parse('themes/Elegant Brit/gtk-2.0/gtkrc')

def create_combo_box(self):

    client_store = gtk.ListStore(str)

    for f in ("a","b","c"):
        client_store.append([f])

    comboBox = gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(client_store) # Error occurs here
    renderer_text = gtk.CellRendererText()
    comboBox.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
    comboBox.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)
    return comboBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error tells you, there is no `new_with_model()` method in `gtk.ComboBox`. See the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html).

Instead, use `comboBox = gtk.ComboBox(model=client_store)`.